# ¿Cuál es la mejor forma de hacer un Performance Test de un algoritmo en PHP?

Tags: php

Estoy trabajando con algoritmos de ordenación y quise comprobar, solo por curiosidad, la vieja pregunta ¿Cuál es el algoritmo de ordenación más rápido?

Hice el típico script PHP para obtener el tiempo que se demora un algoritmo pero el resultado me confunde:

```
<?PHP

function microtime_float(){

    list($useg, $seg) = explode(" ", microtime());
    return ((float)$useg + (float)$seg);
}

$tiempo_inicio = microtime_float();

/* inicio del algoritmo de ordenación */

/* aqui va el algoritmo a observar*/

/* Fin del algoritmo de ordenación */

$tiempo_fin = microtime_float();
$tiempo = $tiempo_fin - $tiempo_inicio;

echo "Tiempo empleado: " . ($tiempo_fin - $tiempo_inicio);

?>
```

Hice algunas pruebas con distintos [métodos de ordenación](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/44676047/algoritmos_de_ordenacion.php) con una secuencia de números pequeña. y los resultados son demasiado distintos en cada prueba:

Por ejemplo: los resultados del **Método Quick Sort:** para la misma secuencia de 5 números fue la siguiente:

```
1 2 3 4 5 Tiempo empleado: 4.8160552978516
1 2 3 4 5 Tiempo empleado: 3.0994415283203
1 2 3 4 5 Tiempo empleado: 9.0122222900391
1 2 3 4 5 Tiempo empleado: 5.5074691772461
etc, etc
```

Como esto me pareció descabellado probé con una secuencia de 9999 números aleatorios y el resultado fue mucho más estable ya que el entero casi siempre era el mismo y solo cambiaban los decimales,

No obstante me surge la pregunta ¿Es profesional este método de testear performance en PHP? ¿Hay alguno mejor? ¿Siempre tendremos que llevar al extremo nuestros algoritmos para testearlos?

Comment: [Esta respuesta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1202746/1065197) me parece más convincente sobre el tema

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Es muy buena esa respuesta. Yo esperaría a que alguien traduzca esta respuesta o de alguna de su propia autoridad con el fin de mejorar la comunidad stackoverflow en español.

Comment: Espero que también alguien la traduzca. Lo haría yo pero estoy algo atareado =\ al menos con eso puedes resolver tu problema :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aquí traduzco [la respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200214/how-can-i-measure-the-speed-of-code-written-in-php/1202746#1202746) cuyo enlace ha aportado @LuiggiMendoza. Algunas adaptaciones del término *profiling* talvez sean mejorables, pero espero que sea de utilidad.

---

Hay (por lo menos) dos soluciones:

Una bastante "primitiva" sería usar `microtime(true)` antes y después de una porción de código, para obtener el tiempo transcurrido durante su ejecución; otras respuestas ya decían esto y daban ejemplos, así que no diré mucho más.

Esta es una buena solución si pretendes comparar instrucciones entre sí; como comparar dos tipos de funciones, por ejemplo (es mejor si se hace miles de veces, para asegurarse de regular cualquier "elemento perturbador").

Sería algo así para ver cuánto tiempo se necesita para serializar un array:

```
$before = microtime(true);

for ($i=0 ; $i<100000 ; $i++) {
    serialize($list);
}

$after = microtime(true);
echo ($after-$before)/$i . " sec/serialize\n";
```

No es perfecto, pero sirve, y no se tarda mucho en prepararlo.

---

La otra solución, la cual funciona bastante bien si quieres identificar qué función es la que consume mucho tiempo en un script entero, sería usar:

- La extensión [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/), para generar información de depuración del script
- Software que lea la información de depuración, y te muestre algo legible. Conozco tres:

  - [Webgrind](http://code.google.com/p/webgrind/) ; interfaz web ; debería funcionar en cualquier servidor Apache+PHP
  - [WinCacheGrind](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wincachegrind/) ; sólo en Windows
  - [KCacheGrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html) ; probablemente sólo en Linux y similares ; prefiero éste, por cierto

Para obtener los archivos de depuración, tienes que instalar y configurar Xdebug ; echa un vistazo a la página [Profiling PHP Scripts](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler) de la documentación.

Lo que suelo haces es no activar el profiler por defecto (*genera archivos muy grandes, y lo ralentiza todo*), sino usar la posibilidad de enviar un parámetro llamado `XDEBUG_PROFILE` como dato GET, para activar el *profiling* sólo para la página que necesito.

La parte relacionada con el *profiling* en mi `php.ini` se ve así:

```
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0              ; Profiling desactivado por defecto
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1      ; Profiling se activaría al solicitarlo mediante el parámetro GET
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = /tmp/ouput_directory
xdebug.profiler_output_name = files_names
```

(*Lee la documentación para más información*)

Este pantallazo es de un programa en C++ con KcacheGrind:
[image: perfilado con KcacheGrind]
Obtendrás exactamente el mismo tipo de cosa con scripts en PHP ;-)
(Con KCacheGrind, quiero decir ; WinCacheGrind no es tan bueno como KCacheGrind...)

Esto te permite obtener una buena visión de los consumos de tiempo en tu aplicación (y a veces ayuda definitivamente a localizar la función que lo está ralentizando todo ^^)

Ten en cuenta que Xdebug cuenta el tiempo de CPU consumido por PHP ; cuando PHP espera respuesta de una Base de Datos (por ejemplo), no está funcionando ; sino esperando. Luego Xdebug pensará que la consulta a la BD no toma mucho tiempo!
Esto debería perfilarse en el servidor SQL, no en PHP, por lo cual...

Espero que esto ayude :-)

Diviértete !